# Insert xml into another xml using t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-dml

There is received xml file from which I get the frame of consignor.
Then I generate an answer xml where I would like to use some block from source xml. That is why I try to insert "consignor" variable which is instance of xml into another xml instance. 
There is no error, however, it doesn't insert the value... 
What can be wrong?

```
DECLARE @source_vsd xml,
        @output_vsd xml


SELECT @source_vsd = N'<vd:vetDocument xmlns:vd="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/vet-document/v2">
             <vd:certifiedConsignment xmlns:vd="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/vet-document/v2">
                <vd:consignor xmlns:vd="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/vet-document/v2">
                  <dt:businessEntity xmlns:dt="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/dictionary/v2">
                    <bs:uuid  xmlns:bs="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/base">04ceb142-053d-11e1-99b4-d8d385fbc9e8</bs:uuid>

                  </dt:businessEntity>
                </vd:consignor>
                <vd:consignee xmlns:vd="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/vet-document/v2">
                  <dt:businessEntity xmlns:dt="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/dictionary/v2">
                    <bs:uuid  xmlns:bs="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/base">cbee869d-5405-4181-a1d8-7e8c8af4597b</bs:uuid>
                  </dt:businessEntity>
                </vd:consignee>
              </vd:certifiedConsignment>

            </vd:vetDocument>
            '
DECLARE @consignee xml,
        @consignor xml

DECLARE @t table(output_vsd_xml xml)  

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES( 'http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/g2b/applications/v2' as merc,
    'http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/vet-document/v2' as vd,
    'http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/dictionary/v2' as dt,
    'http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/base' as bs)
        SELECT
            @consignee = T.C.query('./vd:consignee[1]'),
            @consignor = T.C.query('./vd:consignor[1]')  
FROM   @source_vsd.nodes('/vd:vetDocument/vd:certifiedConsignment') T(C) 

DECLARE @szLocalTransactionId nvarchar(max),
        @szLogin nvarchar(max),
        @szDeliveryDate nvarchar(max)

SELECT @szLocalTransactionId = N'q1234',
        @szLogin = N'login',
        @szDeliveryDate = N'2015-09-28T17:17:00:00';

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES( 'http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/g2b/applications/v2' as merc,
                    'http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/vet-document/v2' as vd,
                    'http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/dictionary/v2' as dt,
                    'http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/base' as bs)
SELECT @output_vsd = (
SELECT  @szLocalTransactionId as 'merc:localTransactionId',
        (SELECT @szLogin as 'vd:login' FOR XML PATH ('merc:initiator'), ELEMENTS, TYPE),
        (SELECT @szDeliveryDate as 'vd:deliveryDate' FOR XML PATH ('merc:delivery'), ELEMENTS, TYPE)
FOR XML PATH ('merc:processIncomingConsignmentRequest')
)
SELECT @output_vsd as without_inserted_value

select @consignor as inserted_value

SET  @output_vsd.modify('
    declare namespace merc="http=api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/g2b/applications/v2";
    declare namespace vd="http=api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/vet-document/v2";
    declare namespace dt="http=api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/dictionary/v2";
    declare namespace bs="http=api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/base";
    insert sql:variable("@consignor") 
    into (/merc:processIncomingConsignmentRequest/merc:delivery/vd:deliveryDate)[1]')

SELECT @output_vsd as with_inserted_value
```

Comment: Is this question solved? Do you need further help?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is some issue with update of a XML variable, because as soon as you put your value into the table (and move namespaces into `with namespaces()` section) everything starts to work as it's supposed to:

```
insert into @t (output_vsd_xml)
values (@output_vsd);

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
    'http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/g2b/applications/v2' as merc,
    'http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/vet-document/v2' as vd,
    'http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/dictionary/v2' as dt,
    'http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/base' as bs
)
update t set output_vsd_xml.modify('
    insert sql:variable("@consignor")
    as first into /merc:processIncomingConsignmentRequest[1]/merc:delivery[1]/vd:deliveryDate[1]'
)
from @t t;

select * from @t;
```

The table was already in your code, only it was unused :)

Answer (score 0):

Regrettfully you did not state your expected output, so my answer needed some requests to my magic crystall ball. I'm quite sure, this can be solved a bit easier:

```
DECLARE @output_vsd XML;

DECLARE @source_vsd XML =
N'<vd:vetDocument xmlns:vd="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/vet-document/v2">
    <vd:certifiedConsignment xmlns:vd="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/vet-document/v2">
    <vd:consignor xmlns:vd="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/vet-document/v2">
        <dt:businessEntity xmlns:dt="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/dictionary/v2">
        <bs:uuid  xmlns:bs="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/base">04ceb142-053d-11e1-99b4-d8d385fbc9e8</bs:uuid>
        </dt:businessEntity>
    </vd:consignor>
    <vd:consignee xmlns:vd="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/vet-document/v2">
        <dt:businessEntity xmlns:dt="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/dictionary/v2">
        <bs:uuid  xmlns:bs="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/base">cbee869d-5405-4181-a1d8-7e8c8af4597b</bs:uuid>
        </dt:businessEntity>
    </vd:consignee>
    </vd:certifiedConsignment>
</vd:vetDocument>';
```

--*easy-cheesy*, I use a namespace wildcard together with the *deep search* with `//`

```
DECLARE @consignor xml = @source_vsd.query(N'//*:consignor[1]');

DECLARE @szLocalTransactionId nvarchar(max)= N'q1234';
DECLARE @szLogin nvarchar(max) = N'login';
DECLARE @szDeliveryDate nvarchar(max) = N'2015-09-28T17:17:00:00';
```

--You can add your XML directly within the XML's generation. No need for a table or any call to `.modify()` - at least I assume so. No need for sub-selects, just to add deeper nesting. This can be done with an `XPath` like alias. Otherwise you'd get your namespace declarations repeatedly (not wrong but very annoying!).

If you need to include namespaces `dt` and `bs` just add them. But they are not used here...

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES( 'http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/g2b/applications/v2' as merc,
                    'http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/vet-document/v2' as vd)
SELECT @output_vsd = 
(
    SELECT  @szLocalTransactionId as [merc:localTransactionId],
            @szLogin as [merc:initiator/vd:login],
            @szDeliveryDate as [merc:delivery/vd:deliveryDate],
            @consignor as [merc:delivery/*]
    FOR XML PATH ('merc:processIncomingConsignmentRequest')
);

SELECT @output_vsd;
```

I did not know, where to place the consignor. This is my output:

```
<merc:processIncomingConsignmentRequest xmlns:vd="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/vet-document/v2" xmlns:merc="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/g2b/applications/v2">
  <merc:localTransactionId>q1234</merc:localTransactionId>
  <merc:initiator>
    <vd:login>login</vd:login>
  </merc:initiator>
  <merc:delivery>
    <vd:deliveryDate>2015-09-28T17:17:00:00</vd:deliveryDate>
    <vd:consignor xmlns:vd="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/mercury/vet-document/v2">
      <dt:businessEntity xmlns:dt="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/dictionary/v2">
        <bs:uuid xmlns:bs="http://api.vetrf.ru/schema/cdm/base">04ceb142-053d-11e1-99b4-d8d385fbc9e8</bs:uuid>
      </dt:businessEntity>
    </vd:consignor>
  </merc:delivery>
</merc:processIncomingConsignmentRequest>
```